# How to select 2 column 5 and 9 from a text file lacking header in command line terminal?

Tags: python, command-line, biopython

If I have the following code shown below. On the command line, if execute ls function, I see this result. However, I want to cherry pick some columns 5 and 9 for instance. How to do that? PS. I am a novice in programming :). Thank you in advance.

`ls how.txt`

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 w w 665K Nov 14 12:00 xxx.pdb
-rw-rw-r--. 1 x x 404K Nov 14 12:00 yyy.pdb
-rw-rw-r--. 1 y y 165K Nov 14 12:00 zzz.pdb
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe the output to ls to awk this way::

```sh
ls -l |awk "{ print $5, $9 }"‘
```

> 

You will get the column 5 and 9 separated with a space character.
It is really fast, and need very little memory.

You can parse easily the lines later on python with `" ".*split(line)`

Comment: it worked thank you very much for the direction @Iñigo